# Integrating Salesforce with Informatica Cloud

Tags: integration, informatica

We are working on a POC on Salesforce-Informatica cloud REST API integration. 
Please let me know the process/step by step information on how to integrate Salesforce with Informatica Cloud REST API, say push data from a .csv(or oracle) to Salesforce and pull(read) data from Salesforce to .csv.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details:

Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx2KKdQBP98

Document : https://network.informatica.com/docs/DOC-15311

Thanks,

Vipul